# Sorting pyspark Dataframe's columns

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Good morning,
I'd like to ask you if I can change the order of dataframe columns based on the number of null values in pyspark. 
For example: one column contains 5 null values, the second one contains 3 null values, and the third contains 4 null values. The new dataframe must sorted like this: [second column, third column, first column].
I hope you help me. Thank you

Comment: adding an example dataframe can be helpful in answering

Comment: Thank you for answering. Well The dataframe is created from a csv file via the commend: dataframe=spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').load('/dbmeta_en.csv'). It contains 24 columns. Some of these columns have null values. If you want I snip a picture of the dataframe